# How to have actual calendar in a slicer in power bi?

Tags: powerbi

When our power bi report runs it runs it for current date which is created by Relative slicer.  Our user would also like to have some options to select different date ranges using an actual calendar and clicking on it after the initial report has been run using a current date filter.  The way which is done in SSRS.

Comment: There's currently no way of doing what you want unless you import visuals from the marketplace such as Beyondsoft Calendar or Calendar by Tallan.

Answer (score 0):

Use a data slicer other than List, Dropdown or Relative, all other visualizations (Between, Before, and After) provide a calendar interface when you select the date:

[image]