# Power BI - Calendar Filter

Tags: calendar, powerbi, datefilter

This may sound like a dumb question but is there some way to create a filter that will open a calendar and after the click, it will show data only of the specific day?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54486463/how-to-have-actual-calendar-in-a-slicer-in-power-bi

Comment: Vote for this related idea: https://ideas.powerbi.com/ideas/idea/?ideaid=7bb7eea1-b02b-4dfe-9e8d-6464669df74e

Comment: @AlexisOlson, sorry, I forgot to reply. Your suggestion was quite helpful. Thanks. Much appreciated.